# How to remove branch from a remote (on Atlassian Stash/Bitbucket)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I want to delete a branch from Atlassian Stash (a sort of github clone) in order to revert my changes. Please let me know what command will do this?

What I know is `git branch –D  prod-652` deletes the branch from local. How can I delete it from Atlassian Stash?

Comment: The unfortunately-named Atlassian Stash is a proprietary Git code hosting solution.  I'm not sure who though this name was a good idea.  (The name is indicative of the many other issues the app has.)

Answer (score 40):

Here are the commands:

```
git branch –D branch-name (delete from local)
git push origin :branch-name (delete from stash)
```

Note the colon (:) in the last command.

Comment: `git push origin` has nothing to do with what git calls a "stash", but rather with what git calls a "remote".  So it sounds like your question was actually about deleting a branch on a "remote".  See [How do I delete a git branch both locally and remote?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/1256452).

Comment: As per the comments above, I believe the question is about the Atlassian product 'Stash' which is a Git hosting solution. The question should probably be renamed to "How to remove branch from a remote (on Atlassian Stash)"

Comment: In the UI the option appeared in 2.1 for merged branches and in 2.8 in general: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-3347 and https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2753

Answer (score 24):

In Stash (2.10), go to the Branches view.  You can select Delete from the Actions button

Comment: What if there a pull request opened with that branch? Stash doesn't allow to delete that branch in that case. How to delete it then?

Comment: @user3527975 reject the pull request

Comment: exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 16):

> Branches view -> Delete(select from options)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree) (Windows/Mac only) on your client machine you can do it from there by right clicking on the remote branch and choosing delete. (Under the hood it does the same commands as [Praveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19363681/12663))